# how to use a texture on each side of the same face

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, texture-painting, vertex-groups

I have walls of paper, for this model, I want to know if you can use different textures in the same lane, for example using a brick texture on the outside of the face, and a white texture on the inside of it face ???[image]

Answer (score 2):

Same as above but using Blender Render - it has to use nodes, there isn't a way without it. By using the Geometry node, I plug the Front/Back input to the Factor of the color mix node that is sent to the material color node. At this stage, you can then plug your image textures into the two colors of the color mix node, and indicate the UV Map name there in the Geometry node.[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Cycles Render, use an *Input* > *Geometry* node > *Backfacing* output as a factor to mix your 2 shaders:

[image]

Comment: in blender render or in cycles?

Comment: it's in Cycles, I don't know for Blender Render

Comment: jejej ok, it's a good start, now I have a base to learn it, I guess it works very similarly in blender render, based on this example it will not be difficult to discover the way to do it in blender render, Thank you

Comment: Maybe someone will answer for Blender Render, anyway you should now work with Cycles or Eevee, as 2.8 doesn't use anymore Blender Render, except if you absolutely need to use it for a particular reason?

Comment: Maybe you should switch to Cycles Render though  ;)  also, Eevee seems really cool, and even if the 2.8 UI seems a bit crippling, I'm sure it will improve

Comment: i need learn how I need to learn what blender can do, how it does it and what its limits are, my university project, refers to creating a 3D engine, I like blender render orque is light and very effective when it comes to toon style, so that for an anime, comic or cartoon animation it seems better than cycles or evve I do not have to be battling a world of nodes, and at this moment I'm not interested in getting involved with learning raytrace, the information load at this moment is brutal and Stressful

Comment: I suppose that of the points that I find a banality does not allow me to mark your answer as good, but I have already written down a reminder in my agenda to do it as soon as I acquire the level to do it