# How to display a image texture only on the outside of a object (cylinder)?

Tags: texturing, uv

I am currently trying to texture a soda cup, but have some issues with the UV mapping I think, because the alpha image that I add on the cup is also visible on the inside of the cylinder. What I want is that it is only visible on the outside of the object. I modelled the cup only with a cylinder object.

**Material details**
I've added the texture using nodes and a RGBMixer to get the transparent image. As you can see, the image is also visible inside the cup.

I tried searching for it on the internet, but didn't find anything related. Hope some can help me out!

[image]

Comment: If you want the inside of the cup to be plain white, either take the UV islands that represent that area and move them to an all-white part of the texture, OR use a second (all-white) material for the inside of the cup.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

If the object has different surfaces for the inside and outside of the cup, just assign a white material to the inside.

If there is no thickness and you are seeing the backface of the object on the inside use the *Geometry > Backfacing* information to control the mix between two different shaders.

[image]

Read more about the Geometry node here:

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html?highlight=backfacing

[how to use a texture on each side of the same face](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/127997/how-to-use-a-texture-on-each-side-of-the-same-face/127999#127999)

If you are using a solidify modifier read this answer:

[Add different textures to front and back of plane with solidify?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56823/add-different-textures-to-front-and-back-of-plane-with-solidify/56825#56825)

Comment: I recreate above node layout, but don't see my image. Even if I change the mapping values.. What do I wrong?

Comment: See edited answer